# Javascript loops with If else while

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I am beyond lost in my class .. its nnot exctly a step by step class so i am lost here .. any help ?

this is the code i have so far ..

```
    var var1 = 10;
    var var2 = 20;
    var wksum = var1+var2;
if (var2 < 30);
    {
        if (wksum < 30 )
            {
            var1 - 2;
            var2 + 1;
            }
        else 
            {
            var1 - 1;
            var2 + 3;
            }
    }
document.write(var2);
```

this is what it has to do ..

```
start
  var1 = 10
  var2 = 20
  wksum = 0
  rslt = 0
  do while var2 < 30
     wksum = var1 + var2
     if wksum > 30
        var1 = var1 - 2
        var2 = var2 + 1
     else
        var1 = var1 - 1
        var2 = var2 + 3
     end if
  end while loop
  rslt = var1 + var2
  display rslt
end
```

Comment: You may need to provide additional information, like what the expected result is, what's actually happening, etc.

Comment: It does not work because the statement `var1 = var1 - 2` does not equal `var1 - 2;` Plus no where in your code are you looping.

Comment: Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

`var1 - 2;` does not do anything. You want to set a new value to var1 like `var1 -+ 2;` or `var1 = var1 - 2;`.